# How to activate cppcheck rules with Sonar C/C++ plugin

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I just installed an evaluation version of the C/C++ plugin [SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/). The documentation says:

- set sonar.cpp.cppcheck.path to cppcheck executable -> done
- Activate some Cppcheck rules in your quality profile -> **How to do that?**

I couldn't find how to activate cppcheck rules. If I browse the quality profile, I can see **60 rules**. If I try to filter rules from cppcheck repository, then none appear. So what should I do?

*Additionnaly, I used to run cppcheck priori to analysis, and then use Sonar C++ Community plugin, which contains 219 cppcheck rules. My first guess was to inherits SonarSource profile from Community profile, but they don't share the profile type : C/C++ vs c++. So I couldn't achieve this (and consequently don't know if that is the solution I'm seeking).*

Comment: If you're trying to test the SonarSource C++ plugin, this means that you have asked for a trial license and you should then write to the commercial support mailing list if you want some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a misunderstanding:

- **rules** column in the **Quality profiles** page indicate the number of active rules, not the total number of available rules for the profile
- the profile page filters by default **active** rules, which makes inactive rules hidden

The solution was to remove the filter on the **Activation** field, and then activate all rules as indicated in the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).